# dynamic mindate based on data-attribute for jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, custom-data-attribute

I have an input element

```
<input id="order_neediton" class="form-control hasDatepicker" type="date" name="order[neediton]" data-notice="3">
```

and the jquery datepicker like so

```
$(function() {
    $("#order_neediton").datepicker({ constrainInput: false , maxDate: "+1m", minDate: "{$('#order_neediton').attr('data-notice')}d"});
  });
```

so as to have the miniumum date start 3 days from today.

But it does not work, how should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
$(function () {
    var min = $('#order_neediton').attr('data-notice');
    $("#order_neediton").datepicker({
        constrainInput: false,
        maxDate: "+1m",
        minDate: min + "d"
    });
});
```

Comment: Great! This works. Will accept the answer in 6 mins.